# Why are there no times in any of my GDataEntryCalendarEvent?

Tags: objective-c, ios, google-api, google-calendar-api, gdata

I am using a `GDataServiceGoogleCalendar` to anonymously fetch a `GDataFeedCalendarEvent` from a public url. But I am absolutely unable to retrieve times from any of the resulting `GDataEntryCalendarEvent` objects. I can read the title, so I believe the API works, but somehow the times arrays are lost somewhere.

The service is instantiated as follows:

```
- (GDataServiceGoogleCalendar *)calendarService {

    static GDataServiceGoogleCalendar* service = nil;

    if (!service) {
        service = [[GDataServiceGoogleCalendar alloc] init];

        [service setShouldCacheResponseData:YES];
        [service setServiceShouldFollowNextLinks:YES];
        [service setIsServiceRetryEnabled:YES];
    }

    return service;
}
```

This is the code where the data is retrieved:

```
for (GDataEntryCalendarEvent *event in eventEntries) {
    NSString *title = [[event title] stringValue];

    GDataDateTime *startTime = nil;
    GDataDateTime *endTime = nil;

    NSArray *times = [event times];
    GDataWhen *when = nil;
    if ([times count] > 0) {
        when = [times objectAtIndex:0];
        startTime = [when startTime];
        endTime = [when endTime];
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my code or the way I connect? The sample app retrieves the dates successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google API requires the use of an actual identified user even to access the public data.
So no access to most API call s is granted until an authenticated user account is being used.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but I can not answer what is wrong with your code. I had problems with the date of the events, and that was my solution that works great for me:

Hope it will help you:

```
         NSArray *events = [feed entries];  

        [events enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
              GDataEntryEvent *entry = [events objectAtIndex:idx];

             for (NSUInteger i=0; i<[[entry times] count]; i++) {
             NSDate * startDate = [[[[entry times] objectAtIndex:i] startTime] date];
             NSDate * endDate = [[[[entry times] objectAtIndex:i] endTime] date];
         } 
         }];
```

There might be a better way but this works.

Comment: Do you retrieve the data anonymously (without Auth)? I suspect It might be the reason of my problem.

Comment: Can you explain your question?